# Open a folder from a button in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that I would like to open a folder.  The folder directory is saved in cell S47 and looks like (C:\Template\2020-05\Open).  My current code opens the file explorer but not to the location of the cell directory.

```
Sub openfolder()
Dim fPath As String
fPath = Sheet4.Range("S47").Value
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & fPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong with this code but I feel like its a simple solution that I'm just skipping over.

Comment: It works for me. If the explorer is opening "my documents" folder then it means that path doesn't exists. Ensure there are not leading or trailing spaces in the cell `S47`. Best is to manually open the folder in explorer and copy the path from there and then paste it in excel.

Comment: Same for me. Works as expected. Cannot reproduce your issue. It even works with spaces in the path (which usually causes issues).

Comment: My button keeps opening my quick access folder. My directory is a bit more complicated as that was an example so I'm assuming that is where my issue is arising.  My actual directory is **S:\H&S\5 - Projects\2020\20200115 - Auto\Sol Bod\001-00-123456 - Sample\Drawings**  It is copy/pasted from the file explorer so I'm not sure what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your exact code:

```
Sub openfolder()
Dim fPath As String
fPath = Sheet4.Range("S47").Value
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & fPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Using:

[image]

and my Desktop opened:

[image]

Suggest you re-check the path in **S47**.
Also make sure the data is in `Sheet4`

Comment: My actual directory is **S:\H&S\5 - Projects\2020\20200115 - Auto\Sol Bod\001-00-123456 - Sample\Drawings** It is copy/pasted from the file explorer so I'm not sure what is going on... It still just opens my quick access folder

Comment: Even using a simple directory copy/pasted as **C:\Users\joshL\Desktop\Projects** it only opens the quick access folder. Any ideas where I could be having issues? @Gary's Student

Comment: @JoshL  My `Path` contains no **space** characters ..........................  **Try your code on a local sub-folder which also has no space characters in its path**

Comment: @JoshL  Make sure VBA has the privileges to open the sub-folder.

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb.. The cell was located in sheet2... I'm sorry everyone for this waste of your time but thank you for your help

Comment: @JoshL  Don't feel dumb ...........................it HAD to be something simple!